# EOD not ending?

Tags: php

[image]

```
<?php

// Page class

class Page {

// Declare a class member variable
var $page;
var $title;
var $year;
var $copyright;

// The Constructor function
function Page($title, $year, $copyright){
// Assign values to member variables
$this->page = '';
$this->title = $title;
$this->year = $year;
$this->copyright = $copyright;

// Call the addHeader() method
$this->addHeader();
}

// Generates the top of the page
function addHeader(){
$this->page .= <<<EOD
                <html>
                <head>
                <title>$this->title</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                <h1 align="center">$this->title</h1>
                </body>
                EOD;
    }
}




?>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The EOD; must be at the very beginning of the line.. no white space or anything before it

Quote from the manual:

> Warning
>   It is very important to note
>   that the line with the closing
>   identifier must contain no other
>   characters, except possibly a
>   semicolon (;). That means especially
>   that the identifier may not be
>   indented, and there may not be any
>   spaces or tabs before or after the
>   semicolon. It's also important to
>   realize that the first character
>   before the closing identifier must be
>   a newline as defined by the local
>   operating system. This is \n on UNIX
>   systems, including Mac OS X. The
>   closing delimiter (possibly followed
>   by a semicolon) must also be followed
>   by a newline.
>
> If this rule is broken and the closing
>   identifier is not "clean", it will not
>   be considered a closing identifier,
>   and PHP will continue looking for one.
>   If a proper closing identifier is not
>   found before the end of the current
>   file, a parse error will result at the
>   last line.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't indent the heredoc marker, it isn't recognized with the leading spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say the actual problem but take a look at heredoc docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc